# I have issues with tokenizing a list of files that I read from a directory. Below is my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

```
import glob
import os
import nltk.data
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk import sentiment
from nltk import word_tokenize

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()


tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')


files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'speeches', '*.txt'))


text = []

for file in files:
    #open the file and then call .read() to get the text

with open(file) as f:
        text.append(f.read())

sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

and printing polarity scores for each one.

```
for sentence in sentences:
        print(sentence,  file=open('sentiment1.txt', 'a'))
        scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
        for key in sorted(scores):
                print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='', file=open('sentiment1.txt', 'a'))
        print()
```

I have five text files in the 'speeches' folder which was successfully read but the issue is that the output file (text) is of list type instead of string and tokenize expects a string or byte as its argument. Please assist me with a tweak as I have read that this might be an issue with Python 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
# below is the sentiment analysis code written for sentence-level analysis
import glob
import os
import nltk.data
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
from nltk import sentiment
from nltk import word_tokenize
# Next, VADER is initialized so I can use it within the Python script
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
# I will also initialize the 'english.pickle' function and give it a short 
# name
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
#Each of the text file is listed from the folder speeches
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'speeches', '*.txt'))

text = []

#iterate over the list getting each file
for file in files:
#open the file and then call .read() to get the text
with open(file) as f:
    text=f.read()
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence,  file=open('sentiment1.txt', 'a'))
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(sentence)
    for key in sorted(scores):
            print('{0}: {1}, '.format(key, scores[key]), end='',  
                               file=open('sentiment1.txt', 'a'))

    print()
```

I have tested the code without an empty list so that there will not be a need to append but the method is only picking the last text file in the folder. I am writing the code segment again so you can see clearly what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `text` is initialized as an empty list, and you append the contents of the five input files into `text`, you can use the `join()` function to smash these into a single string for use by `tokenizer.tokenize()`:

```
text = []

for file in files:
    #open the file and then call .read() to get the text
    with open(file) as f:
        text.append(f.read())

text_str = "".join(text)   # or "\n".join(text)
sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text_str)
```

Alternatively you can initialize `text` as an empty string and concatentate the contents of each file, in turn:

```
text = ""

for file in files:
    #open the file and then call .read() to get the text
    with open(file) as f:
        text += f.read()

sentences = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
```

Comment: Thank you @grand_chat. The option  '\n'.join(text ) did the magic. I had used .join() before but apparently I was not using it in the right segment. Thank you and God bless.